# stat_summary does not recognize aes()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I want to plot sina plots with `stat_summary` function fro each colored group:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
    ggplot(diamonds |>  filter(cut=="Fair"), aes(x=cut, y=price, color=clarity )) + 
        scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2", guide = "none")+ 
        geom_violin(fill = "gray80", linewidth = 1, alpha = .5) +
        geom_sina(alpha = .25) +
        coord_flip()+
        stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_se", colour = "black", linewidth = 1, size = 0.5)
```

But somehow stat_summary does not recognize the `aes()`, so I only get one mean (black point). How can I make it so it will be for each group?
[image]

I tried `group=interaction(cut, clarity)` - but it still not what i was looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put `group = clarity` inside the `aes` of `stat_summary`. You'll need to add a `position_dodge` too:

```r
ggplot(diamonds |>  filter(cut=="Fair"), 
       aes(x=cut, y=price, color=clarity )) + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2", guide = "none")+ 
  geom_violin(fill = "gray80", linewidth = 1, alpha = .5) +
  geom_sina(alpha = .25) +
  coord_flip()+
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_se", colour = "black", 
               linewidth = 1, size = 0.5, aes(group = clarity),
               position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

[image]

Comment: position = position_dodge(0.9) <- this part I cant do, as the dodging number can be different for different plots, I want it to inherit the amount of dodging done from geom_sina layer

Comment: One layer cannot directly inherit from a different layer. If you want both layers to have the same amount of dodge, you could specify it directly in both layers.

Comment: but when i do geom_violin and geom_sina- they both get dodged automatically - why is that? and why the amount of dodging is same for both?

Comment: They are dodged automatically because the default position for both is `position = "dodge"`. This is not the case with `stat_summary`, which has zero width and is not dodged.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you've got the x-axis set to `cut`, when you really want it to be set by `clarity`. For the violin plots, it staggers them to show the points, but stat_summary doesn't work for that. If you set `x=clarity`, then all the plot elements will be properly set apart by x-axis group:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
ggplot(diamonds |> dplyr::filter(cut=="Fair"), aes(x=clarity, y=price, color=clarity )) + 
    scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2", guide = "none")+ 
    geom_violin(fill = "gray80", linewidth = 1, alpha = .5) +
    geom_sina(alpha = .25) +
    coord_flip()+
    stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_se", color = 'black', linewidth = 1, size = 0.5, )
```

[image]

Comment: this is just a demo, i need to have x as a cut